# Which (non-trace class) operators have a well-defined trace (if any)?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, trace

On a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, it is well known that trace class operators have a finite trace. However, there are operators which are not trace class but have a finite trace, e.g. the [unilateral shift](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3039962/138382). Then, consider a (bounded) operator $A$ such that
$$
c=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\langle x_n,A x_n\rangle<\infty,
$$
for some orthonormal basis $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots\}$. I'm not sure whether this is enough for the trace of $A$ to be defined in a basis independent way. Namely, $\mathrm{tr}(A)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\langle y_n,A y_n\rangle=c$ for **any** orthonormal basis  $\{y_1,y_2,\ldots\}$.

In the classics von Neumann's book on Mathematical Foundations of Quantum Mecanics, Sec. II.11, he commented **this is true** (in fact, he did not consider trace class operators) using essentially the following argument:
$$
c=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\langle x_n,A x_n\rangle=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\langle x_n,y_m\rangle \langle y_m, A x_n\rangle=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\langle y_m, A x_n\rangle\langle x_n,y_m\rangle=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\langle y_m,A y_m\rangle.
$$
However, it is not clear to me that the double sum can be switched. Using that $|\langle u,y_m \rangle \langle y_m, v\rangle|\leq \frac12 (|\langle u,y_m \rangle|^2+|\langle v,y_m \rangle|^2)$ it is obtained that
$$
\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\langle x_n,y_n\rangle \langle y_n, A x_n\rangle
$$
is absolutely convergent. Is this enough for the summation switch?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**: As Robert Israel points, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\langle x_n,A x_n\rangle$ must be absolutely convergent. Is it enough?

Answer (score 1):

If the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle x_n, A x_n \rangle$ is only conditionally convergent, you can take the same basis $x_n$ but rearranged, and get a sum that diverges, or converges to an arbitrary value: see the [Riemann rearrangement theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem).

Comment: thank you!, of course you are right. However, let me ask then the same question under the condition $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|\langle x_n,Ax_n\rangle|<\infty$. It might be the case that $A$ is not trace-class (e.g. unilateral shift). However, can its trace be defined in a basis independent way?

Comment: the answer to my last questions is also negative; with the unilateral shift is easy to prove that there are orthonormal basis $\{y_n\}$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|\langle y_n,Ay_n\rangle|=\infty$. I guess the trace class condition $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|\langle x_n,Ay_n\rangle|<\infty$ for any orthonormal sets $x_n$ and $y_n$ is the only one which ensures a proper definition of trace.

Comment: @NessunDorma I think that if $A$  is bounded, if suffices to demand that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle x_n, A x_n \rangle$ converges for some basis. Then this is true for any basis.

Comment: @Filippo, thanks, but again the unilateral shift seems to be a counterexample to your point

Comment: @NessunDorma Why?

Comment: @Fillippo, $S$ is bounded and $\sum_{n=1}\langle x_n , S x_n\rangle=\sum_{n=1}\langle x_n , x_{n+1}\rangle=0$, but if $\{y_n\}$ is the basis of Martin Argerami's answer,   $\sum_{n=1}\langle y_n , S y_n\rangle$ with oscillating

Comment: @NessunDorma Thank you very much for your explanation, I just realized that I didn't properly read the definition of trace class: The requirement is **not** just that $N\mapsto\sum_{n=1}^N \langle x_n, A x_n \rangle$ converges for some basis, but that $N\mapsto\sum_{n=1}^N \langle x_n, |A|x_n \rangle$ converges for some basis. My reference is "Spectral Theory and Quantum Mechanics, 2nd edition" by Valter Moretti, Definition 4.32 and proposition 4.36.

Comment: $|A|:=\sqrt{A^*A}$ is the modulus of $A$, definition 3.80. It would be interesting to see if $\sum_{n=1}\langle x_n , |S| x_n\rangle$ fails to converge.

Comment: @Filippo $|S|=1$ so indeed $\sum_{n=1}\langle x_n,|S|x_n\rangle=\sum_{n=1} 1$ diverges.

Comment: @NessunDorma Is that because each unitary operator $T\colon H\to H$ has the property $T^*T=TT^*=1$? If yes, this would imply that all unitary operators on an infinite dimensional hilbert space are not trace class.

Comment: @Filippo $S^*S=1$ but $SS^*\neq1$. Surely, there is no isometric trace class operator on an infinite dimensional Hilbert space.

Comment: @NessunDorma Oh, okay, thank you for letting me know. So $S$ is an isometry, but not unitary. As you can clearly see, I don't really have any background in functional analysis or mathematical quantum mechanics, but I learned a lot from this discussion :)

Answer (score 1):

Without getting too creative, stay with the unilateral shift and consider the orthonormal basis $\{y_m\}$ given by
$$
\tfrac1{\sqrt2}\,(x_1+x_2),\tfrac1{\sqrt2}\,(x_1-x_2),\tfrac1{\sqrt2}\,(x_3+x_4),\tfrac1{\sqrt2}\,(x_3-x_4),\ldots
$$
In this basis, the diagonal of $S$ is
$$
\tfrac12,-\tfrac12,\tfrac12,-\tfrac12,\ldots
$$

Comment: yes, thank you! I have realized of that as commented to Robert Israel. I guess the trace class condition $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|⟨x_n,Ay_n⟩|<\infty$ for any orthonormal sets $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ is the only one which ensures a proper definition of trace. For a moment, I thought that a condition like  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|⟨y_n,Ay_n⟩|<\infty$ could work, but I think it only does for normal operators. Is any book addressing the issue that no non-trace class operator admits a trace?